# How to plot ema line only if cross over is true in the last candle

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

I would like to plot ema10 line, only if the ema10>ema20 in the last date(today)

Plot(ema10[1]>ema20[1]?ema10:na) plots for the dates where ema10>ema20.

But I wanna plot the ema10 for all the dates, if last value of ema10> last value of ema20.

Thanks